# Can jQuery Mobile be inserted into an appMobi XDK app?

Tags: jquery-mobile, appmobi

I am new at appMobi and want to know if I can insert jQuery Mobile into my app. I tried 
to insert the code from the documentation site http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/about/getting-started.html
but it doesn't work. I also tried to use aux_web of appmobbi but it gave me errors.

These are the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'availableTransitions' of undefined jq.ui.min.js:133
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'availableTransitions' of undefined all.js:58
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'autoLaunch' of undefined index.html:61
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/truetype:
```

---

i make an app by used only jqMobi and i test it in a android phone but it has a lot of bugs. So i download the phonegap XDK from appmobi.com . But i have a problem there too because i can't used camera from phonegap and at the same time jquery mobile.But if i use only the camera or only the jquery mobile it works fine.Do you know what i have to do or where i have to see because i saw all documentations in appmobi and i can't find any informations for phonegap XDK appmobi. 
thk

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your jquery mobile app into appMobi, however, you will notice things like slow transitions on Android. AUX is no longer supported. We release jqMobi which does a much better job as far as UI is concerned. You can download it from https://github.com/appMobi/jQ.Mobi